# IP based 'hosts' file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dns, ip, hosts

I'm new to this, so bear with me a bit.

I'd like to write a batch file that can replace the etc/hosts file, depending on which VLAN I' m in when I log in. 
ie: When I log in and I've got the xxx.xxx.102.xxx local IP, I'd like to use the hosts1 file. When I log in and I've got the xxx.xxx.103.xxx local IP, I'd like to use the hosts2 file.

So basically based on the output of an ipconfig, scan it for a "102" and a "103" and when that number is in the output, it could replace the hosts file in the Windows directory.

Ideas?

Comment: Cant you just assign a static local IP to your MAC-address in the router config?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (102 102 103) do (

  ipconfig | find "xxx.xxx.%%a.xxx" >nul 2>&1 && copy /y hosts%%a "%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
)
```

will work if you have  admin permissions and your hosts files are anemd hosts101 hosts102 ...

Answer (score 0):

you might try this. I use `findstr`'s Regex capabilities here:

```
ipconfig | findstr /er "[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.102.[0-9][0-9]*" && copy hosts1 "%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
ipconfig | findstr /er "[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.103.[0-9][0-9]*" && copy hosts2 "%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the regexp will handle single numerals in the IP address.

Comment: @foxidrive   this Regex can- obviously- not test for validity of an IPv4. But imo it can _find_ a (valid) IPv4 in the output. Why do you think, it will not handle  single numerals ? `[0-9][0-9]*` is the same like `[0-9]+` in ERE, that is `one or more`.